# Get a unique list from list in python

Tags: python

I'm struggling with this task. I have a list1 below.
I want to get the unique taxes (gst, pst,etc.) and get the total for each one.

```
list1 = [{
    "taxes": [{
        "amount": 1393,
        "rate": {
            "object": "tax_rate",
            "country": "CA",
            "created": 1643646734,
            "display_name": "PST",
            "percentage": 7.0,
            "tax_type": "pst"
        }
    }, {
        "amount": 995,
        "rate": {
            "object": "tax_rate",
            "country": "CA",
            "created": 1643646734,
            "display_name": "GST",
            "percentage": 5.0,
            "tax_type": "gst"
        }
    }, {
        "amount": 205,
        "rate": {
            "object": "tax_rate",
            "country": "CA",
            "created": 1643646323,
            "display_name": "Special",
            "percentage": 4.0,
            "tax_type": "special"
        }
    }]
}, {
    "taxes": [{
        "amount": 2000,
        "rate": {
            "object": "tax_rate",
            "country": "CA",
            "created": 1643646734,
            "display_name": "PST",
            "percentage": 7.0,
            "tax_type": "pst"
        }
    }, {
        "amount": 1000,
        "rate": {
            "object": "tax_rate",
            "country": "CA",
            "created": 1643646734,
            "display_name": "GST",
            "percentage": 5.0,
            "tax_type": "gst"
        }
    }]
}]
```

How can I get the list2 below? This one has all unique taxes, then get the total amount for each one. Also, I just need a few values from the list1.

```
list2 = [
    {
        "tax_name": 'GST',
        "tax_rate": 5.0,
        "tax_amount": 1995
    },
    {
        "tax_name": 'PST',
        "tax_rate": 7.0,
        "tax_amount": 3393
    },
    {
        "tax_name": 'Special',
        "tax_rate": 4.0,
        "tax_amount": 205
    },
]
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Please show us your best attempt at solving the problem and explain how exactly it fails to give you the expected output. Otherwise, this might look like you are just trying to get us to write code for you for free...

Comment: Apart from typing out your list/dictionary structures, what code have you tried to implement?

Comment: As a hint: use a dictionary with the `tax_type` as a key and then loop over your list filling the dictionary with the appropriate values.

Comment: @Thierry Lathuille: Sorry, I didn't mean that. I'm new to Python, and I would like to have a solution if someone knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is the following code:

```py
def extract(data):
    result = {}
    for element in data:
        for tax in element["taxes"]:
            name = tax["rate"]["tax_type"].upper()
            rate = tax["rate"]["percentage"]
            amount = tax["amount"]
            if name in result:
                result[name]["tax_amount"] += amount
            else:
                result[name] = {
                    "tax_name": name,
                    "tax_rate": rate,
                    "tax_amount": amount
                }
    return list(result.values())
extract(list1)
```

The idea is to have a dictionary indexes by the name of your tax.
If the name is already present in the keys of the dictionary, we just update the total amount by adding the amount of the current tax.
If the name is not present in the keys of the dictionary, then we create a new entry with the name, the rate and the current amount.